# Can I use “serve sb for sth” in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage

Anybody can tell me this sentence is grammatically correct when I use “serve for”? I used Google Translator, the translation shown is not what I’d like to express.

> Starting as a practitioner in logistics, I **served a lot of clients for their valuable, perishable, or fragile shipments**.

What I mean is “When I was a junior clerk in the logistics industry, I provided service to a lot of clients for their valuable, perishable, or fragile shipments.” I’d like to use “serve sb for sth” to replace “provide service to sb for sth”, but unsuccessful the Google translator shows it ungrammatically.

If you have any idea about how to better use “serve” in this sentence, please let me know.

Comment: What do you want to express?

Comment: Please don't shorten the words: use *somebody* and *something*. Assuming that's what you actually do mean. (Assuming it *is* what you mean, I'm not sure why you are using *for* in the sentence.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably not used "served" as it sounds like you are serving food or something.
I would say:

> Starting as a practitioner in logistics, I provided shipping services
>   for valuable, perishable, and fragile items (or products) to many clients.